# Objects in storyboard keep pinning underneath prototype cell

Tags: ios, ios7, storyboard

I saw only one other question where someone had a similar problem trying to drag out a tab bar.  I am personally trying to just drag out a UIPickerView and have it sit along the bottom edge of the view; i want it to pop up only when the user taps the bottom left calendar icon.  But every time i drag it out it keeps getting placed underneath the prototype cell!  It's driving me a little crazy.

Any help for getting the picker to sit along the bottom edge of the view, or how to just write this all in code to solve my problem, would be appreciated!!  Here's what it looks like right now...

[image]

Comment: Are you using a UITableViewController or a UIViewController with a table as a subview?

Comment: a UITableViewController

Comment: A UITableViewController's only view is the table view, so anything you add will become part of the table. If you want the picker at the bottom, you should switch to a UIViewController so you can add other subviews besides the table.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do: 
Present your UIPickerView as a custom input view.

There of course is no textfield for you to trigger it, so when you tap the respective Tool Bar Button, add an invisible textfield to your window, make it the first responder and send the data from the UIPickerView back via a delegate.

Code for the invisible textField would look like:

```
UITextField *invisiText;
    if (!invisiText) {
        invisiText = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        invisiText.inputView = theInputView.view;
        invisiText.delegate = sender;
        [theView.window addSubview:invisiText];
    }
    [invisiText becomeFirstResponder];
```

Sender in this case is the View from where you trigger the custom input view and "theInput.view" will be the xib with your custom UIPickerView. Works like a charm, reusable across the board and a huge timesaver for this and all projects to come.

Let me know if you need more information.